# Woocommerce Deprecated template

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to update the woocommerce deprecated templates.I managed most of them except this one.Maybe some of you can help me out.Thank you very much.

Turned the wp debug on and i get this.

*Notice: WC_Product::get_related is deprecated since version 3.0! Use wc_get_related_products instead.*

This is the actual line ofcode now

```
$related = $product->get_related( $posts_per_page );
```

And I changed it to this

```
$related = $product->wc_get_related_products( $posts_per_page );
```

But then i get this:

*Fatal error: Call to undefined method WC_Product_Simple::wc_get_related_products()*

**Here is the full code**,thank you.

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $product, $woocommerce_loop;

if ( empty( $product ) || ! $product->exists() ) {
    return;
}

$related = $product->wc_get_related_products( $posts_per_page );


if ( sizeof( $related ) == 0 ) return;

$args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_related_products_args', array(
    'post_type'            => 'product',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'  => 1,
    'no_found_rows'        => 1,
    'posts_per_page'       => $posts_per_page,
    'orderby'              => $orderby,
    'post__in'             => $related,
    'post__not_in'         => array( $product->id )
) );

$products = new WP_Query( $args );

$woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $columns;

if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <div class="wc_related sugpro_box products">

        <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Suggestions you might enjoy with this products', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
         <div class="pro_foods_list">
        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

            <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

                <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>
        </div>

    </div>

<?php endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
?>
<div class="recip_prod">
        <h2>Recipes with this products</h2>
            <ul class="recip_list">
<?php 
 $post_id = get_the_ID();
$nameqry1="select * from wp_posts where ID IN (select r.rec_id from wp_posts as p ,  wp_recipes as r where p.ID=r.post_id AND p.ID=".$post_id.") AND `post_status`='publish'";  

$Rquery =  mysqli_query($mysqli,$nameqry1);

if(mysqli_num_rows($Rquery) > 0)
{ 
    while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Rquery))
        { ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url');?>/search-recipes/?rc-page=<?php echo $rows['ID']?>"><?php  echo $rows['post_title'];?></a></li>
<?php   }
}else{
    echo "This Product Recipes Not Available";
}
?>
           </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Try using `$related = wc_get_related_products( $product->get_id(), $posts_per_page );` instead

Comment: @Und3rTow thank you , it seams to work.